яндекс тормозит selenium python
я недавно познакомился с библиотекой selenium в python. Мой код успешно взаимодействует с сайтом, но иногда сайт ждет ответа от запроса на рекламу Яндекса и останавливает программу, пока ответ не придет. Это занимает примерно 10 секунд. Я бы хотел как-то удалить этот запрос, чтобы моя программа не дожидалась ответа. Как это можно сделать?

Цепляйтесь к элементу, который вам нужен. Допустим:
driver.wait_for_element_visible("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/button", timeout=10).click()

